# Maven Custom Parent property from Module

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-module

I cant access, from a Maven module, to a property defined in the  `properties` section of the parent.
As a matter of fact When I launch the build below the warName is the default one.

This is the parent Pom

```
....
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.speed.pms</groupId>
    <artifactId>PMS-Main</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
        <name>PMS Main Build Project</name>

    <properties>
            <context-root>PMS-CUSTOM</context-root>
        </properties>
     <modules>
        <module>../PMS-WEB</module>
     </modules>
....
```

And this is the module

```
...
 <parent>
        <groupId>com.speed.pms</groupId>
        <artifactId>PMS-Main</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
      </parent>
    <artifactId>PMS-WEB</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>PMS-WEB Webapp</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <web.resource.dir>src/main/webapp</web.resource.dir>
    </properties>
    <build>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Context root from parent project -->
                    <warName>${context-root}</warName>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${web.resource.dir}</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
....
```

While I can use the  ${project.parent.arctifactId} property. 
I try also  ${project.parent.properties.context-root} but without success. It should be simple but I cant understand Which is my errror? Shouldn't be the properties inherited from the parent in a Module?

Answer (score 2):

People in the Maven user list help me to find the solution. I post the reply

> while your ../PMS-WEB section in parent pom 
>   references the child in the same directory, your 
>   / is undefined, therefore expecting the parent 
>   to be one level up, not on the same level.

I change the child module parent section in

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.speed.pms</groupId>
    <artifactId>PMS-Main</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <relativePath>../PMS-Main/</relativePath>
</parent>
```

and everithings works.

Thanks to milos

Davide

Answer (score 0):

There are another solution. Maven 3 in first step looking for parent `pom.xml` in one level up directory. If they can not find this file there then try to extract `pom.xml` from repository.

So solution is to install parent project before run maven in child.